# Generate Multi-Layed PSD with ImageMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am looking for a way to convert a fully in imagemagick generated image as a psd with all "elements" in the image on a seperate layer.

My current command looks like this:

```
convert -size "300x200" 
    ( xc:none -background "#ff0000" ) 
    ( xc:none -gravity "SouthEast" -pointsize "20" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'This is a Test'" -mosaic ) 
    ( xc:none -gravity "SouthWest" -pointsize "12" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'Magni natus veniam.'" ) 
-layers merge test.psd
```

But it returns a broken PSD. Adding `-layers merge` will return a working PSD but with (obviously) only one layer.

What am i doing wrong to get multiple layers?

Comment: Why do you have -mosaic inside the parentheses? You only have one image in that parenthesis. Do you want each parentheses as a separate layer? You have to create a first layer that is the flattened layer of all the layers.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have each parenthese as a layer. I just tried a few things that's why the mosaic might be a leftover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Unix syntax for your command in ImageMagick. It seems to work for me. Is this what you want?

```
convert -size "300x200" -background "#ff0000" \
\( xc:none \) \
\( xc:none -gravity "SouthEast" -pointsize "20" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'This is a Test'" \) \
\( xc:none -gravity "SouthWest" -pointsize "12" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'Magni natus veniam.'" \) \
\( -clone 0-2 -layers merge \) \
-reverse test.psd
```

Here is the Windows equivalent.

```
convert -size "300x200" -background "#ff0000" ^
( xc:none ) ^
( xc:none -gravity "SouthEast" -pointsize "20" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'This is a Test'" ) ^
( xc:none -gravity "SouthWest" -pointsize "12" -fill "#f486d8" -draw "text 9,9 'Magni natus veniam.'" ) ^
( -clone 0-2 -layers merge ) ^
-reverse test.psd
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i am looking for! Only problem is that Photoshop warns me about "this file is using a unsupported mixing mode. Do you want to use the normal mode instead?" and after pressing "OK", everything is fine

Comment: I got the same message. I do not know what to what it refers.